# Maximum K for K-way merge

Tags: mergesort

I am trying to find out, what is maximum K for K-way merge sort or if there is any maximum.
Time complexity of this algorithm is O(nlogK). I have been looking for it for several hours with no luck. Can somebody just link me to some article where it is explained, or tell me if there is some limit and why is it so?
Also I'd like to know if there is some value of K that is recommended to use, that is most efficient.

Comment: why would there be an arbitrary maximum for k?

Comment: Since I haven't found anything about it I don't know, maybe memory limitations, slower speed with too high K, something like that

Comment: Once K**2 exceeds the size of the data set, adding additional "ways" can be counterproductive.

Comment: The goal for the initial partitioning of the data to be sorted is to stay within the limits of fast-access memory.  If you are spilling to the swap file, you are trying to handle too much data at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of an internal (memory only) sort, the total number of operations on the data remains about the same regardless of K. Let x = n log2(n). A 2 way merge sort requires x moves and worst case x compares for a total of x + x = (2)x operations. (technically there are a bit less than x compares even in worst case, but x is close enough to get the idea here). A 4 way merge sort requires (1/2)x moves and worst case (3/2)x compares, so still a total of (1/2)x + (3/2)x = (2)x operations. If compares are faster than moves, then 4 way merge sort is faster, if moves are faster than compares, then 2 way merge sort is faster. There's also the issue of variables like pointers or indices being kept in registers or on the stack, for a 4 way merge, you'd want 16 registers (like X86 in 64 bit mode). As an example where moves are faster, consider the case where an array of pointers to objects are sorted, only the pointers are moved, but the objects are compared (which involves a pointer dereference for each object).

For an external sort, the internal sort to created sorted chunks on an external device (disk drives, or in the old days a bunch of tape drives) can be be any algorithm, the K way part just merges the chunks. There's a trade off between the number of external sort passes and K large enough so that a K way merge becomes cpu bound instead of I/O bound. The total time is I/O time + any cpu time that goes beyond I/O time. Gnu sort for large data files uses K = 16. The K way merge is done using a K element minimum heap, where each heap entry corresponds to a structure (or the equivalent), that holds a chunk id, record index or pointer, number of records for a chunk remaining in memory, number of records remaining in the chunk). After the initial creation of the minimal heap with K entries, the front element of the heap corresponds to the structure with the currently smallest element (assuming ascending sort) of the K entries. That element is moved to be output, the next element is read from that chunk, and the heap is updated to reflect where the next element places what was the front entry within the heap. Once the end of a chunk is reached, the merge becomes a K-1 merge, then a K-2 merge, until there's only 1 chunk left which is copied.